# Laravel Validation errors are not being translated if locale changed at runtime

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-blade, laravel-middleware

My Laravel app has `locale` defaulted to english (in `config/app.php`). There is a middleware that checks every request and set the locale as per user preferences.

Below is middleware code

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $langs=['en', 'ar'];
    $appLang=app()->getLocale();
    if (request()->has('lang')) {
        $requestLang=request()->get('lang');
        if ($requestLang != $appLang && in_array($requestLang, $langs)) {
            app()->setLocale($requestLang);
        }
    } else {
        request()->merge(['lang' => $appLang]);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

The locale is set as per the url parameter lang for eg. `http://localhost:8000/admin/departments?lang=ar`

Everything works well, except with validation errors. When the locale is set to 'ar', hardcoded in `config/app.php`, it shows translated errors irrespective of locale being set by the middleware. But if the locale is set by middleware, the views are translated but the validation errors are still english.

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the json files for translations? The validation/authentication text bits are placed in separate files. Do a check on **resources > lang** subfolder. Inside the lang subfolder you can create other additional subfolders like "en" or "es" or for any other language you want.

Comment: the translations are in `resources/lang/ar/validation.php`

Comment: Thats it, those are the files that you should translate and it should work. At least thats what I have, if the locale is set properly then it should show everything in the proper language